# Could not start weblogic in Linux in Hyperion server

Tags: linux, weblogic, hyperion

I have applied patch in **Oracle Hyperion server related to Weblogic patch 10.3.6.0.200714** which requires java 7 so for this I have copied java1.7.221 files into the server and changed the references of **Jrockit1.6 to point to Java 7 in setDomainEnv.sh** file. After doing this when I am starting weblogic through ./startWeblogic.sh, it is giving me error:

Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
[image]

I have the same script changes in Windows where it is working fine however in Linux I am facing error.
Any one know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Read the logs, it says "*Unrecognized options: -XXtlasize:min=4k,preferred=64k*".  Fix that, try again.  Note that this should be posted as text, never post images of text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take into account that XXtlasize is a jrockit option, so if you have moved to Java 7 you need to remove it.

When using EPM with Java7, there are more steps to follow that just adjusting references in setDomainEnv.sh. Please check **Doc ID 2351499.1** in Oracle Support for the details.

Thanks.